# How to patchValue to radio button in angular?

Tags: angular, radio-button, formarray, form-control, patchvalue

How to patchValue to radio button in angular?
I have to patch rating for particular skill, how to do this in typescript?

**HTML Code**

```
 <tbody formArrayName="skills">
                <tr class="skill-tr" *ngFor="let skill of skills; let i = index">
                    <td class="table-data res-td" class="skill-td">
                        <b value="skill.skillId">{{skill.skillName}}<span>:</span></b>{{skill.skillDescription}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="radio" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="radio" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="2" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="radio" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="3" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="radio" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="4" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="radio" formControlName="{{ i }}" [value]="5" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
```

**Cosole log for rating based skill: Image**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsRa1.png)

I want to patch radio button rating value based on skill.

**UI Screenshot**

[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTIUE.png)

**Response which I have to patch to the radio button**
I copied the response from the console,

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Object0
rating: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, ratingId: 1, rating: 5, ratingName: 'Outstanding'}
skill: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, skillId: 9, skillName: 'Overall Evaluation', skillDescription: 'Developer'}

Object1
rating: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, ratingId: 1, rating: 5, ratingName: 'Outstanding'}
skill: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, skillId: 8, skillName: 'Organizational Fit', skillDescription: 'Developer'}

Object2
rating: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, ratingId: 1, rating: 5, ratingName: 'Outstanding'}
skill: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, skillId: 7, skillName: 'Flexibility', skillDescription: 'Developer'}

Object3
rating: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, ratingId: 1, rating: 5, ratingName: 'Outstanding'}
skill: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, skillId: 6, skillName: 'Interpersonal/Communication Skills', skillDescription: 'Developer'}

Object4
rating: 
{createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, ratingId: 1, rating: 5, ratingName: 'Outstanding'}
skill: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, skillId: 5, skillName: 'Motivation/Initiative', skillDescription: 'Developer'}

Object
5
rating: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, ratingId: 2, rating: 4, ratingName: 'Excellent-exceeds requirements'}
skill: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, skillId: 4, skillName: 'Professional Impression', skillDescription: 'Developer'}
 
Object6
rating: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, ratingId: 3, rating: 3, ratingName: 'Competent-acceptable proficiency'}
skill: {createdBy: 0, lastUpdatedBy: 0, skillId: 3, skillName: 'Relevant Background/Special Skill Set', skillDescription: 'Developer'}
```

Comment: You could use indexer like this: this.skills.at(0).patchValue('2')

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: Please post your form model from the component. It would be helpful if you posted the text of `resourceRatingData` instead of just a screenshot. 
I do not understand what this does: `<ng-container *ngIf="i == i">`. Doesn't `i` always equal `i`?

Comment: I am not using that ng-container. I forgot to remove that line

Comment: @Meqwz I have added the response in question section please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like another FormControl or FormGroup

As you have a FormArray of FormControls you need "feed" with an array of values

```
//create an array of values
const data=this.yourObject.map(x=>x.ratting.ratting)

//use patchValue
this.form.controls.skills.patchValue(data)
```

Well, `yourObject` looks like not ordered so we are going to create an array of values "ordered"

```
const data:number[]=[];
this.myObject.forEach((x:any,index:number)=>{
    data[x.skillId-1]=x[index].ratting.ratting
})
//or using reduce
const data=this.myObject.reduce((a:number[],b:any)=>{
    a[x.skillId-1]=b.ratting.ratting
    return a
},[])
```

Some point about your code

1. It's would prefer use `[formControlName]="i"`better than
   `formControlName="{{i}}"`
2. Always it's better iterate over formArray.controls and use the index
   to show the "labels"

   ```
      <tr class="skill-tr" *ngFor="let skill of
                   skillsArray.controls; let i = index">
        ...
        <b [value]="skills[i].skillId">{{skills[i].skillName}}<span>:</span>
      </tr>
   ```

   Where you have a getter

   ```
   get skillsArray()
   {
      return this.form.controls.skills as FormArray
   }
   ```

NOTE: when we make a patchValue in a FormArray we need take account that the FormArray and the data have the same length